# TypeError while iterating

Tags: python

I am trying to load a 3x3 grid which shows 9 of the words from an external file, but the code below produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Name\Documents\IT Work\New folder\Version 4.py", line 49, in <module>
    for line in range:
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

Code:

```
ay = open('Words.txt','r')
output_list = ay.read().strip().split('.')

with open('Words.txt') as f:
    words = f.read().splitlines()

for line in (ay):
        f.append(line.strip())

if len(ay) == 10:
                print(listofwords[0]+' '+listofwords[1]+' '+listofwords[2])
                print(listofwords[3]+' '+listofwords[4]+' '+listofwords[5])
                print(listofwords[6]+' '+listofwords[7]+' '+listofwords[8])

for line in range:
    print(5)
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: you have to specify range in for line in range:

Comment: You are  trying to iterate over a reference to a function, read the docs https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#func-range

Answer (score 1):

In Python a for statement is supposed to be called using an iterable. [range](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) is a function which returns a list in Python 2.x (a special kind of iterable), you should pass a number to it for it to return the desired iterable.

Just change your code to something like that:

```
number_of_iterations = 5

for line in range(number_of_iterations):
    print(5)
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: You are right @PadraicCunningham... will clarify it on the commands